How to emulate Powershell keyboard text selection with WSL in Windows Terminal?
I'm new to using WSL and Windows Terminal. I'm running the default Ubuntu install in Windows 11 and I'm looking for a way to have keyboard text selection behave the same way it does when running PowerShell, or any text editor for that matter. I'd like to be able to select text or whole lines with Shift + arrow keys, delete whole words with ctrl + backspace... those kinds of features. Is it possible to do that without having to set up each key binding individually?
Thanks
